# arcpy.SearchCursor and unexpected results

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor, arcgis-10.7

I'm stuck on results that arcpy.SearchCursor is outputting. I'm accessing a table on a database connection. When I run this, it crashes with an error:
argument of type 'Row' is not iterable

I ended up changing the code below, to simply print the row, and it comes back with:

> `<geoprocessing row object object at 0x048F8440>`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing?

```
import arcpy
import csv

MyData = arcpy.SearchCursor("c:/users/Rando/AppData/Roaming/ESRI/Desktop10.7/ArcCatalog/DB.sde/RandoTable")

Phrase = "Some Words"
for row in MyData:
    if Phrase in row:
        TheAnswer = row.getValue("TheHeader")
```

Comment: Don't use the deprecated `arcpy.SearchCursor` for new code. Instead use `arcpy.da.SearchCursor`, which returns a list of lists, and could potentially honor the `in` operator. (You'd still be better off using the `where_clause` parameter to implement the `if`.)

Comment: What field are you trying to search for "Some Words" in exactly?  You can't just search a row for a phrase, you have to search the values of fields in a row for a phrase.

Comment: ThePhrase is generated from a previous search cursor. I've got to jump through 6 files, all tying a code together.

For Example, in this last run, ThePhrase = "24A49032-0882-6D12-C0CD-0A810AA0087B"

I'm trying to match that up to the 'SIGNAL' field of that table

Made it a little further with the .da
At least I failed in a different way. (It didn't find a match.) I'm probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

@Vince
.da for the win

```
import arcpy
import csv

### My Column Headers
fields = ['SearchingField1', 'SearchingField2', 'SIGNAL']

myData = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("c:/users/Rando/AppData/Roaming/ESRI/Desktop10.7/ArcCatalog/DB.sde/RandoTable", fields)

phrase = "Some Words"
for row in myData:
    if phrase in row:
        theAnswer = row[2]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).